# How to open latitude and longitude in map using Linking in react native?

Tags: react-native

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{

       var lat = 50.894967;
       var long = 4.341626;
                   var url = "http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lat>,<long>";                        Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
                  if (supported) {
                  Linking.openURL(url);
                   } else {
                  console.log('Don\'t know how to go');
                  }
                  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
               }}>
```

This is the code i have used , tried concatenation of lat and long to the url but i am able to open system default map but its not showing that location.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var url = `http://maps.apple.com/?ll=${lat},${long}`;
```

instead of

```
var url = "http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lat>,<long>";
```